# Install shared library without being sudo user

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

I have to install an `.so` library to a directory in my home directory because I'm not `sudo` user. I've created the env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<user>/lib/`. I have created a directory `/home/<user>/lib` and I've copied the file `libXss.so.1.0.0` and created a sym link to it called `libXss.so.1` in that directory but when I launch the program that depends on that library it gives me the error:

error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: How exactly did you "put the two files" in the directory? normally, `libXss.so.1` would be a symbolic link to `libXsso.so.1.0.0` I think (rather than a separate file)

Comment: I simply copied the two file in the directory

Comment: I am convinced the system won't link those libraries if the system has a version of them, which will take precedence. Regardless your methodology looks sound. It does look like the command line you show is lacking a bit of text `/home/<user>/lib/...` as opposed to `/home//lib/` which would not match to ~/lib of any user, although I suspect this was not what you typed.

Comment: I've edited the question after I've did the step in the first answer, now should be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libXss.so.1 is a symlink and it seems you copied it as a file:

Try this:

```
$ rm /home/<my_username>/lib/libXss.so.1
$ ln -s /home/<my_username>/lib/libXss.so.1.0.0 /home/<my_username>/lib/libXss.so.1
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<my_username>/lib/ /path/to/your/program
```

Comment: I've did the step and now the error is: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @AndreaBellizzi, what is the output of `file /home/<my_username>/lib/libXss.so*`

Comment: /home/andreabelliz/lib/libXss.so.1:     symbolic link to `libXss.so.1.0.0'
/home/andreabelliz/lib/libXss.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e375c9284e3378de2c6f1cdf7ccfae50db33220f, stripped

Comment: The error message in the first comment point to the loader not being able to find the shared library... What system are you on? You may have other restrictions if you are running something embebbed for example.

Comment: I'm on CentOS 7 system, other the fact that I'm not sudo user I don't know if I have other restriction.

Comment: Can you share the name of the program? Local testing might help find a solution.

Comment: yes I'm trying to install the ide atom. I've downloaded the tar.gz from this https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.47.0 and I've extracted it into /home/my-user/bin/, then I've made a symlink to the binary in the folder bin and exported the path to this bin directory into the .bashrc file in my home directory.

Comment: It works for me. I moved away the system libraries, it failed, then add LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it worked. I launched it both times with `./atom --no-sandbox`. You should recheck the commands you ran. Also, maybe you are running on ARM aarch64, but if you are not, then you should get the library binaries for your actual platform (it could be x86_64 and then the package to extract the libraries from is [this](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-6.1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)).

Comment: yes I've failed the right package, thank you very much, now it works.

Comment: If it works and answers your question, it is customary to mark the answer as accepted.